# Tab and complete

Tags: bash, readline

Is the key binding for tab to complete in the readline settings set implicitly.  Because when I outputted

```
bind -q complete
```

I got this in return

```
complete can be invoked via "\C-i", "\e\e".
```

Thanks in advance :-)

Interestingly when I typed

```
bind -u complete
```

tab stopped working

Comment: `\C-i` (Control+i) represents `Tab`. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Yes sorry about that, didn't realize

Comment: It's OK, this isn't really intuitive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Text terminals only understand characters, not keys. So special keys like <kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>Backspace</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd> and so on have to be encoded in terms of characters. The [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) character set, which all modern character sets are based on, reserves a space for [control characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character). One such character is [Tab](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab_character#Tab_characters). Because it is character number 9, and `I` is letter number 9, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> is equivalent to pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> in a text terminal.

You can see what character or character sequence a key sends by doing the following in a shell:

1. Start typing `echo -n '` at the prompt.
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, which tells the shell that you really want to enter the next character and not have it treated as an editing command.
3. Press the key (or key combination like <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>) you want information about.
4. Enter `' | hexdump -C` and press <kbd>Return</kbd>.

You'll see a printout of the byte(s) sent by the key in hexadecimal. Bytes 00 to 1f are control characters (`^@`, `^A` to `^Z`, `^[`, `^\`, `^]`, `^^` and `^_`; `^x` is a common notation for the control character obtained by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>).

Comment: how come unless i type ctrl-v tab after an escape like \ it will just print a single space? So if type \ then press Ctrl-v tab it will work but if press just Control-v tab is doesn't I though ctrl-v sort of escapes it already

Comment: @rubixibuc `Ctrl+V` escapes for the part of the shell that reads from the terminal, so e.g. `Tab` means “insert a tab character” and not “complete”. `\` and `'` and `"` escape in the shell as a programming language, so the tab character is used literally and not as a word separator.